# Losing emojis when sending post with JSON

Tags: android, json, post, emoji

I have a String with plain text emojis in my app (like this :) , when I put this String in a JSON and POST it to the server, the server takes the String and sends an email with it. When I receive the email in my phone, instead of emojis I receive "?".

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of points this can go wrong. You have to be more specific:

- Is Android not recognizing the TextView properly and encoding the emoji as a `?` ?
- Is the problem happening from the server? What server technology you're using?
- Is the problem with your email client not being supportive of UTF-8 encoding?

I suggest you check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2GTivnMCR-Y on the latest support library (26) that adds support for emoji TextViews. Also, please check the relevant points I mentioned

Comment: 1: Android recognises the emojis without any problem. The "?" appears only when the String goes throw the server.
2: The server is Apache, the code is in Java and is a REST service.
3: Is not the mail client because the same mail client shows the emojis when I send them directly from the app.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am pretty sure that is not an Android problem. I think that the issue is in the server.